certificate verify failed self-signed certificate in certificate chain when using pymongo==4.6.3
I have upgraded pymongo to 4.6.3 version , but post upgrade I am facing below error while connecting to MongoDB
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 662621e393579412bb6b2314, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

Earlier was using pymongo==3.13 and it was working fine. Post upgrade of pymongo I am getting above error.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Looks like you try to connect to Mongo Atlas, i.e. cloud service. How can you have a self-singed certificate? The certificate is provided by the server, i.e. the cloud provider.

All root certificates are self-signed, by definition.  You'll need to get the root certificate that issued the server's certificate and add it to whatever trust store you are using with pymongo.
